Convergence of fourier series in sobolev norm
I am studying Fourier series and would like to understand the properties of the series when dealing with real-valued functions. Specifically, I have the following questions:

Fourier Series and Complex Coefficients:
Given a real-valued function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, the Fourier series can be expressed with complex coefficients. For a function with period $T$, the Fourier series is given by:
$$
   f(x) \sim \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} c_n e^{i \frac{2 \pi n x}{T}}
   $$
where the Fourier coefficients $c_n$ are defined as:
$$
   c_n = \frac{1}{T} \int_{a}^{b} f(x) e^{-i \frac{2 \pi n x}{T}} \, dx
   $$


I have the following questions:

Uniform Convergence for Continuous Functions:
If $f(x)$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, does the Fourier series converge uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$?

Convergence in Sobolev Spaces:
If $f$ belongs to the Sobolev space $W^{k,p}(\mathbb{R})$, does the Fourier series converge in the $W^{k,p}$ norm?


If not for general $p$ can we at least say something for the hilbert space with $p=2$?

$f$ is real iff the Fourier coefficients satisfy $c_{-n} = c_n^*$, so only $c_0$ is real in general.

$\textbf{This is a partial answer, only answering the first of the two questions}$
The answer to your first question is no. There are continuous functions for which the Fourier series even diverges at a point (see e.g. Drawing a continuous function with divergent Fourier series at $x=0$...). This obviously excludes uniform convergence.
There are two results on pointwise and uniform convergence of Fourier series, but they both require slightly more:

If $f$ is continuous (and $2\pi$-periodic) and has left and right derivatives at every point, then the Fourier series converges pointwisely (a theorem by Dirichlet)
If $f$ is continuous (and $2\pi$-periodic) and piecewise $C^1$ (so continuously differentiable with the exception of finitely many points partitioning your interval), then the Fourier series converges uniformly to $f$.

Both theorems even have generalizations for functions that are not continuous but merely have left and right limits at every point. For example if you have that property and in addition have left and right derivatives at every point, you obtain pointwise convergence to $\frac{f(x-)+f(x+)}{2}$, the mean value of the left and right limit.
